# Prove all eigenvalues of $A^*A$ are non-negative

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix. Prove that all eigenvalues of $A^*A$ are non-negative.

Comment: Do you have thoughts on the problem or have tried anything? Regards

Comment: I'm trying to think of where to begin but I cant find a starting ground.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Pick an eigenvector $x$ of $A^*A$ and consider $x^*A^*Ax$.

Answer (score -1):

$A^*Ax=\lambda x\Rightarrow x^*A^*A=\bar{\lambda}x^*\Rightarrow x^*A^*Ax=\bar{\lambda}x^*x\Rightarrow x^*x(\lambda-\bar{\lambda})=0\Rightarrow\lambda=\bar{\lambda}$

Comment: How does $\lambda = \bar \lambda$ imply $\lambda\geq 0$? It just imply $\lambda$ is real. $\lambda$ may be negative.